# nested samba share

Tags: permissions, mount, samba, fstab, cifs

For some reason the share //192.168.1.5/NonMedia/QEveline won't mount by /etc/fstab contents.
The error is

> mount error(13): Permission denied

Why can't I mount a share as another user?
this is the relevant part of fstab

```
#//192.168.1.5/QMedia /mnt/Proxmox5/QMedia cifs ,username=guyf,password=redacted,vers=3.0,sec=ntlmv2,iocharset=utf8,gid=1003,uid=1001,file_mode=0750,dir_mode=0750 0 0
//192.168.1.5/NonMedia/QEveline /mnt/Proxmox5/QEveline cifs ,username=eveline,password=redacted,workgroup=workgroup,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770 0 0
#//192.168.1.5/NonMedia /mnt/Proxmox5/NonMedia cifs ,username=guyf,password=redacted,vers=3.0,sec=ntlmv2,iocharset=utf8,gid=1003,uid=1001,file_mode=0750,dir_mode=0750 0 0
#//192.168.1.5/NonMedia/guyf /mnt/Proxmox5/guyf cifs ,username=guyf,password=redacted,vers=3.0,sec=ntlmv2,iocharset=utf8,gid=1001,uid=1001,file_mode=0750,dir_mode=0750 0 0
```

Proxmox is serving the files with samba.
I have  different usernames (elizabeth,lieslotte,guyf,eveline) they are all in the qnap group.
Every user has his own share which is nested on a //192.168.1.4/NonMedia/username. Only the username should be able to read/edit and delete these usernameshare/files.
I also have shares like //192.168.1.4/NonMedia/QDocuments //192.168.1.4/NonMedia/QGame etc...these shares need to be accessible/editable by every user.
Only the creator of the file can delete his file.

This is an extract of my smb.conf file

```
[QMedia]
path = /mnt/Data/Media
read only = No
guest ok = yes
valid users = guyf eveline @qnap
force create mode = 770
force directory mode = 1770
inherit permissions = yes
writeable = yes
force user = guyf
force group = qnap

[QEveline]
comment = Hier staat media
path = /mnt/QData/NonMedia/QEveline
read only = No
guest ok = No
valid users = eveline
force create mode = 770
force directory mode = 1770
inherit permissions = yes
writeable = yes
force user = eveline
force group = eveline

[guyf]
path = /mnt/QData/NonMedia/guyf
read only = No
guest ok = yes
valid users = guyf 
force create mode = 770
force directory mode = 1770
inherit permissions = yes
writeable = yes
force user = guyf       
force group = guyf

[NonMedia]
path = /mnt/QData/NonMedia
read only = No
guest ok = No
valid users = guyf eveline @qnap
force create mode = 700
force directory mode = 1770
inherit permissions = yes
writeable = yes
force user = guyf       
force group = qnap
```

How does one mount nested shares with different permissions?

Thanks for reading,
Guy

Comment: What does nested mean?

Comment: with nested I mean that different zfs datasets like /mnt/NonMedia/Documents //192.168.1.5/NonMedia/Games etc plus a  dataset /mnt/NonMedia/QEveline are visible for the end user in //192.168.1.5/NonMedia share though some have different permissions. Only Eveline can read/edit delete files in the //192.168.1.5/NonMedia/QEveline share.